# Meteor/React/React-Router4 - redirect in HoC withTracker

Tags: reactjs, redirect, meteor, react-router

I have a collection which includes public and private object. Those which are public should be able to be seen by everyone, private ones — only by their owner. I have the following routes in `react-router` v4:

```jsx
const Routes = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route path="/list/:id" component={OneList} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

And I'd like to redirect if someone goes to a `/list/:id` link if there is no list (or the user doesn't have the right to see it cause it's private and owned by someone else).

I've tried to manage it in my `OneList` component which uses `withTracker` to get its data:

```js
export default withTracker((props) => {
  const data = Meteor.subscribe('database');
  const myLists = Meteor.subscribe('myLists');
  const publicLists = Meteor.subscribe('publicLists');

  const list = List.findOne({_id: props.match.params.id});
  if (list === undefined){
    props.history.push('/');
  } else {
    return {
      currentUser: Meteor.user(),
      listLoading: !publicLists.ready() && !data.ready() && !myLists.ready(),
      list,
      database: Database.find({}).fetch(),
    };
  }
})(OneList);
```

But when I do this I get the follwing error:

```
es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7…:1240 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at keys (<anonymous>)
    at Function.keys (es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7…:1240)
    at MeteorDataManager.calculateData (ReactMeteorData.jsx:85)
    at ReactMeteorDataComponent.componentWillMount (ReactMeteorData.jsx:130)
    at callComponentWillMount (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:14583)
    at mountClassInstance (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:14640)
    at updateClassComponent (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:15022)
    at beginWork (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:15411)
    at performUnitOfWork (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:17379)
    at workLoop (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:17488)

modules.js?hash=abbf998…:13111 The above error occurred in the <ReactMeteorDataComponent> component:
    in ReactMeteorDataComponent (created by Route)
    in Route (created by Routes)
    in Switch (created by Routes)
    in div (created by Routes)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by Routes)
    in Routes

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
You can learn more about error boundaries at /react-error-boundaries.

modules.js?hash=abbf998…:17685 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at keys (<anonymous>)
    at Function.keys (es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7…:1240)
    at MeteorDataManager.calculateData (ReactMeteorData.jsx:85)
    at ReactMeteorDataComponent.componentWillMount (ReactMeteorData.jsx:130)
    at callComponentWillMount (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:14583)
    at mountClassInstance (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:14640)
    at updateClassComponent (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:15022)
    at beginWork (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:15411)
    at performUnitOfWork (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:17379)
    at workLoop (modules.js?hash=abbf998…:17488)
```

From my research it may be because I don't return an object from `withTracker`, but I don't want to, as I want to redirect.

Any idea how to solve this? Maybe my check and redirect should be done inside the router?

Comment: Any chance of switch to using to `react-router` v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To redirect run

```
meteor npm install react-router
```

To redirect in react-router v4 you have to do it in the render function.

```
(list === undefined) &&
  <Redirect to={'/Home'}/>
```

This is a normal if statement or you can do

```
(list === undefined) ?
  <Redirect to={'/Home'}/>
:
  <Redirect to={'/Login'}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly (not tested) insert a

```
<Redirect to={'/login'}/>
```

as a prop into OneList as well, inside of the withTracker wrapping.